# Separate User / Admin API?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, rest, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi tenant app using Angular and Node.js, is it wise to have the same API for both Front End users (Public) and Admin Area users (Tenants)?

The Admin Area will require authentication for viewing and modifying sensitive data but I don't see why the rest of the API can't be left open for the front end which is only querying data?

Is this a good idea? Will it cause problems further down the line?

I'm looking to go for the following application structure:

- Front end:    tenant-name.domain.com   (Open to public)
- Admin area:   domain.com/admin   (with login and token auth)
- API:          api.domain.com

Would it be a good idea to have the client's front end authenticate with the API?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the admin area API calls require an auth token to be passed on all API calls. You can inject the token into the headers with http request interceptors in Angular. A user who does not already have an auth token should have to log in to get one. The injected auth token should be all the security you need.

Comment: Just an addition: you should have `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;` in the interceptors code

Comment: I get that part for the Admin area, what about anonymously authenticating the User area that is open to the public? Would this be unnecessary? There are certain things that should be kind of secure (User orders) but I am trying to avoid sessions

Comment: That's a matter of preference and you'll probably get a lot of different opinions on that. Some production apps with public features use no auth, cookies, or tracking of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to create a token when an anonymous user requests your API. Reason for that is that you can always identify who requested what.